# for loop condition and if statment

Tags: java, list, if-statement, for-loop, break

I have made a for loop and I want the loop to break when the user enters a negative value and then give a message. I do not want the program to calculate the negative value.

```
public class test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> yolo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        double sum = 0;
        output.println("Enter your integers\n" + "(Negative=sentinel)");

        // add the values to your empty Array except the negative entries
        for (int entry = input.nextInt(); entry < 0 ; entry = input.nextInt())
        {
            yolo.add(entry);
            if (entry >= 0 )
            {
                sum += entry;
            }
            else {
                output.println("Your list is empty");
            }
        }
```

I tried using Outerloop:, and break outerloop; but it breaks the loop even at positive integers.

Answer (score 3):

change it to

```
for ( int entry = input.nextInt(); entry >= 0; entry = input.nextInt())
```

because currently the loop is only running when the entered number is < 0.

So the loop has the semantic(meaning):

```
run while the entries are >= 0, read every time from the input to entry
```

So the loop finishes, when a user enters a negative number.

Comment: the loop worked but when i enter a negative value it doesn't give the massage i wanted ~.~

Comment: you can simply add the system.out.println after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
// add the values to your empty Array except the negative entries
```

It looks like you're also missing out a small thing.
What you want to do is:

```
if (entry >= 0){
  yolo.add(entry);
  sum += entry;
}
```

For your problem, I think your for-loop as declared is wrong, because each time you call input.nextInt() it will ask for a new input, and you can put negative values the second time whatever happens.